# MPI_Recv() invalid buffer pointer

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have a dynamically allocated array that is sent by rank 0 to other ranks using MPI_Send()
On the receiving side, a dynamic array is allocated memory using malloc()
MPI_Recv() happens on the other ranks. At this receive function, I get invalid Buffer Pointer error.

Code is conceptually similar to this:

```
    struct graph{
    int count;
    int * array;
} a_graph;

int x = 10;
MPI_Status status;

//ONLY 2 RANKS ARE PRESENT. RANK 0 SENDS MSG TO RANK 1

if (rank == 0){
    a_graph * my_graph = malloc(sizeof(my_graph))
    my_graph->count = x;
    my_graph->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*my_graph->count);
    for(int i =0; i < my_graph->count; i++)
        my_graph->array[i] = i;
    MPI_Send(my_graph->array,my_graph->count,int,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    free(my_graph->array);
    free(my_graph);
    }
else if (rank == 1){
    a_graph * my_graph = malloc(sizeof(my_graph))
    my_graph->count = x;
    my_graph->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*my_graph->count);
    MPI_Recv(my_graph->array,my_graph->count,int,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status)  // MPI INVALID BUFFER POINTER ERROR HAPPENS AT THIS RECV
}
```

I dont understand why this happens since memory is allocated in both sender and receiver ranks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the specific error message you get. It also helps to include the MPI implementation and version.

Comment: I have edited the question as per your suggestion. Using the gcc's compiler (MPICC) version 5.4.0

Comment: The example is neither complete nor verifiable. The code cannot even remotely compile. Please read the page again carefully. Also provide the specific error. GCC is not a MPI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a minimal, working, and verifiable (MWVE) example which Zulan suggested you to make. Please provide MWVE in your future questions. Anyway, you need to use MPI datatype `MPI_INT` instead of `int` for sending and receiving.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct graph{
    int count;
    int * array;
} a_graph;

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int x = 10;
    MPI_Status status;

    //ONLY 2 RANKS ARE PRESENT. RANK 0 SENDS MSG TO RANK 1

    if (rank == 0){
        a_graph * my_graph = malloc(sizeof(a_graph));
        my_graph->count = x;
        my_graph->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*my_graph->count);
        for(int i =0; i < my_graph->count; i++)
            my_graph->array[i] = i;
        MPI_Send(my_graph->array,my_graph->count,MPI_INT,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        free(my_graph->array);
        free(my_graph);
    }
    else if (rank == 1){
        a_graph * my_graph = malloc(sizeof(a_graph));
        my_graph->count = x;
        my_graph->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*my_graph->count);
        MPI_Recv(my_graph->array,my_graph->count,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        for (int i=0; i<my_graph->count; ++i)
        {
            printf("%i\n", my_graph->array[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```